# MQTT protocol on Ingenico's terminal e.g. iCT220

Tags: mqtt, iot

Is there any way to implement **MQTT protocol** on **Ingenico's POS** devices? I am currently working on **iCT220** on which I want to implement IOT project. In this project, I will be sending some bytes (may be 400-1000 bytes) of data to the broker (server).

There are lots of source codes for the library available in the internet, but all make use of Linux or Windows socket libraries, where as Ingenico's devices come with proprietary libraries.

Have anyone implemented similar project on the same devices? Can anyone guide me to the process of implementation?

Thanks in advance,
Pankaj

Comment: This looks like a chip & pin terminal, as such no 3rd party code should be running on it at all.

Comment: @hardillb the code does not access the chip and pin part of the existing terminal application.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you will need to build it from source.
I had a look at several client libraries and it looks that dependencies come mostly from IP stack, so there's very little to be implemented to have it running.
You should expect the proprietary OS issues to be thing of the past in short time - newer terminal lines are based on linux.